# Where can I get a step by step guide to use CASA for obtaining a radio image of a planet like say Jupiter?

Tags: radio-astronomy, jupiter, radio-telescope

I intend to use CASA for processing ALMA data for Jupiter and obtain a proper radio image for Jupiter.
However, is there any specific step by step guide for the same just as is the following for TW Hydrae:
https://casaguides.nrao.edu/index.php/First_Look_at_Imaging

Pls guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember seeing a step-by-step guide for Jupiter with ALMA. There's an old and advanced tutorial for Jupiter with [VLA polarization](https://casaguides.nrao.edu/index.php?title=Jupiter:_continuum_polarization_calibration) though. But if you want ALMA specifically, here's what you can do: you can download some Jupiter observation data from [ALMA data archive](https://almascience.eso.org/aq/), and then follow the NRAO CASA guide for TW Hydrae.